# joints renaming (maya python): loop is tested over for right joint selection, still matching name error

Tags: python, maya

Loop rightly navigates to each joint in the selection and "name" changes each time the loop runs. A simple print statement for "name" ( commenting the rename command ) prints out (( Thumb00
Thumb01 Index00 Index01 Index02 Mid000 Mid001 Mid002 Mid100 Mid101 Mid102 Pinky00 Pinky01 Pinky02 )) the prospective names. Code is still generating "  More than one object matches name " error !!

This script is the beginning point of a code meant to auto rig a hand when the meta bones are selected for each finger. These meta joints are first fed with fixed names, and info related to joints available in each finger is stored in the list "fingers". Each joint per finger is later meant to be renamed. This is where code is generating error!

```
import pymel.all as pm

oSel = pm.ls(sl=True)         # select "meta" joint for each finger in the hand ( thumb to pinky )       

# ---------- rename the MetaJoints --------------
pm.rename( oSel[0] , "metaThumb" )
pm.rename( oSel[1] , "metaIndex" )
pm.rename( oSel[-1] , "metaPinky" )

finCount = len(oSel)

midFinCount = finCount - 3

midFingers = oSel[2:-1]           #  script is desired to run on hands with any number of fingers.
 
i=0   
for phalanx in midFingers:          
    name = "metaMid0" + str(i)
    pm.rename( phalanx , name )     # thus any number of fingers between index and pinky are considered midfingers and renamed accordingly.
    i+=1


# ------------- read each finger as a list of joints --------------    
fingers = []

for jnt in oSel:
    
    childJntsLst = pm.listRelatives( jnt , allDescendents = True, type = 'joint' )
    
    childJntsLst.reverse()                # the joints received are in the tip - parent order. Thus list is reversed.
    
    childJntsLst.insert( 0 , jnt )        # meta joints are fused to the starting of the list
    
    phalange = []    
    
    for phalanx in childJntsLst[:-1]:
         
        phalange.append( ( phalanx.split("|")[-1] ) )         # individual joint is extracted form the absolute name style
    
    fingers.append( phalange )                                # "fingers" would now list all the joints per finger starting from thumb to pinky


# ------------- rename all phalanges ---------------- 
for fing in fingers:                                         # for each finger in the list "fingers"
    i=0 
    for phalanx in fing[1:]:                                 # for each joint in the said finger
        name =  fing[0][4:] + "0" + str(i)                   # pick the name from the first joint in the chain
        pm.rename( phalanx , name )                          # rename all joints with this  name suffixed by digit ( 0,1,2,3.... )
        i+=1
```

Comment: You can use the pymel object renaming which is not based on names but on object ids as much as I know, so instead of `pm.rename(element, "newname"))` you can do `element.rename("newname")`. Maybe this helps to avoid the same name problem.

Comment: nothing works. I even tried to zip function through two lists , one with names and another with respective joints, and then use rename command. Same error.